# Flutter/Dart/Firebase Creating User - This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have following code which does not work somehow:

```
Future<void> createUserWithEmailAndPassword() async {
  //try nutzer erstellen
  try {
    UserCredential userCredential =
    await Auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _controllerEmail.text,
      password: _controllerPassword.text
    );
  } 
  
  catch (e) {
    if (e is FirebaseAuthException) {
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = e.message;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add the userCredential variable so I can use it later on but somehow it give me the following error:

> This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
> Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.dartuse_of_void_result

I want to use the userCredential variable so I can create in Cloud Firestore additional information for a user in a document.

Any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: You may taking value from void function. If function's return type "void" then we can not  get value from that function.

Answer (score 2):

The function createUserWithEmailAndPassword returns indeed a Future containing the UserCredential.

Please make sure that the return type of the function used in the *Auth* class matches the return type of the function *createUserWithEmailAndPassword* provided by *FirebaseAuth*.

It should look like this:

```dart
class Auth {
  static Future<UserCredential> createUserWithEmailAndPassword({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) =>
      FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using

```
Auth()..createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: _controllerEmail.text,
    password: _controllerPassword.text
  );
```

try using

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: _controllerEmail.text,
    password: _controllerPassword.text
  );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).